# How to fix frozen boot screen on R Pi?

Tags: sd-card, boot-issues, ubuntu, image, raspberry-pi-os

I've installed the image [Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) with desktop and recommended software](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_full_armhf_latest) to microSD HC (Smartbuy 32gb) using [Raspberry Pi Imager for Windows](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/imager/imager.exe). Turning my R Pi on leads to [loading screen stuck forever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJCFI.png). Keyboard typing is enabled, but no command works. I double-checked memory card files and performed verification in Raspberry Pi Imager, everything seems to be OK.

I also tried to write OS img using [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) with the same result.

What do I need to check to solve the problem? Since I use Raspberry for the first time, the issue may be very simple.

**UPD**: I've tried other Raspberry Pi OS versions with the same result. `Ubuntu 20 LTS for Pi 2/3/4` provides strange error output:
[image: Output]

**UPD 2, mod attention needed!** Changing card to SanDisk Ultra 32gb resolved all the issues. So, basically, the answer is "It's SD card problem". **But it's still unclear which standard exactly is violated by Smartbuy! Should I open a new question or continue the discussion here?**

Comment: first boot usually takes a while as the root partition is being extended ... does the green LED flash while it "does nothing"

Comment: The green light is on. I've tried to wait more than an hour - no result.

Comment: I don't get what `Keyboard typing is enabled, but no command works` means ... the screenshot does not suggest this to be the case - oh, wait, there is a cursor, sorry - can you add to the question what raspberry pi model you have please

Comment: Also, for a quick test, try the other two variants i.e. `Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) with desktop` and `Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Lite`

Comment: @JaromandaX completely same issue with Raspberry OS lite. Both leds are lit.

Comment: do you have access to a different sd card, preferably a different brand - the brand smartbuy sounds like an oxymoron 

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't. But how could it be if the card is absolutely new and it works fine with my PC and tablet? Of course I've tested the card first: all my devices read/write on it.

Comment: *all my devices read/write on it* - except the pi :p by the way, which model pi is it? Oh, by the way, I have USB thumb drives that work perfectly well on all my devices, except in a raspberry pi, where they don't fail, but are agonisingly slow - so, yeah, working on non-pi doesn't mean it'll work on pi

Comment: Check the steps in [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558)

Comment: @JaromandaX Interesting. I'll buy another SD card for the test. But how do I understand it's suitable? I've read card requirements for Pi and found nothing special there, just microSD 16gb or more.

Comment: you still haven't answered one question - which model RPi do you have?

Comment: @JaromandaX Pi 3 B+

Comment: try bootting from a USB thumb drive instead - boot from USB is enabled by default on that

Comment: About your UPD 2: please create an answer with the solution and accept it after two days. Or better you accept the answer from *Dmitry Grigoryev* because he addressed the problem. Don't place the solution into the question. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years. And no, you should not continue with discussion another question. Discussions does not fit to the question and answer format of this site. You should open a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is getting an SD card from a reputable brand such as Samsung, Sony, SanDisk, Lexar, Transcend, Kingston, PNY, etc. and avoid buying it in a shop which also sells Smartbuy, Goodmem, Kingstick and other "brands" that are either completely unknown to Wikipedia, sound fake, or don't belong to companies producing computer hardware. For instance, Smartbuy is a house brand of Flipkart which is an Indian equivalent of e-bay: they don't produce any electronics, only resell.

Tools such as FakeFlashTest can detect some of the problems plaguing fake SD cards such as mismatch between real and reported capacity. However, some subtle electrical problems may not be detectable on a PC and still cause failures on a Pi.

Comment: If my card is failed how do I describe the problem to get a return? Because if it is there's some kind of issue I can refer to.

Comment: Your guess is right. Everything works without a single issue on SanDisk Ultra 32gb. NOOBS runs fine too while on Smartbuy I got "Formatting error" even without starting. But there's still a question: which standard is violated?

Comment: @JustLogin The exact problem is impossible to trace down without an extensive investigation. Some cheap cards don't support 1.8V which UHS cards are required to support. As a customer, I would simply request a refund for "defective goods", and stay away from no-name cards in the future.